# Ensuring only 1 mandatory parameter is passed to script

Tags: linux, bash, command, programming, getopts

I am writing a shell script and new to getopts for parameter parsing.
What I have are 1 optional and 2 mandatory parameters and what I want to do is ensure that only one mandatory parameter is passed. Right now a basic validation exists but its practically useless long term.
I looked at other examples using if conditions but that fails as well. Using flags inside the cases and calling functions by checking individual statuses also printed all.
What I want is to ensure just 1 mandatory argument is used and an error thrown when more than 1 passed.
Right now, all the options are working in the order specified. Here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

USAGE="Usage : $0 [-r N] (-a|-b)"

#Prompts when there are no arguments passed
if [ "$#" -le 0 ]; then
    echo $USAGE
    exit 2
fi

#the option parsing
while getopts ':n:ab' option
do
    case $option in
        r)
            numlim=$OPTARG
            ;;
        a)
            task1
            ;;

        b)
            task2
            ;;

        *)
            echo "Unknown Param"
            echo $USAGE
            ;;
    esac
done
```

What I want is a hint to how I can go about designing the code in the specified way.

Comment: Don't call tasks within the `case` statement. Just set up vars, then test if 2 or more have been set, then take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable deciding which task to run in the `getopts` loop, then manually check that only one task is chosen. You could do that in various ways, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
task=
set_task() {
    if [ -n "$task" ]; then
        echo "only one of -a and -b may be used" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    task=$1
}
while getopts ':n:ab' option; do
    case $option in
        a)  set_task a;; 
        b)  set_task b;;
        *)  echo "unknown option" >&2
            exit 1;;
    esac
done
if [ "$task" = a ]; then
    echo do task a...
elif [ "$task" = b ]; then
    echo do task b...
else
    echo "invalid or unspecified task" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. This brought me much closer to the solution I was aiming for.